# Linux file sort with incomplete columns

Tags: linux, file, sorting, multiple-columns

I need to sort a file by the first column, if there is a numerical entry, and by the second column when there is none in the first. It looks basically like this:

```
3 - foo bar
1 1 foo bar
- 5 foo bar
2 2 foo bar
- 4 foo bar
```

and I need the output then to be

```
1 1 foo bar
2 2 foo bar
3 - foo bar
- 4 foo bar
- 5 foo bar
```

Is there any nice way to do that in linux with a single command?
Thanks!

Comment: And what do you expect to happen if both columns have a - ?

Comment: That doesn't happen, one of the columns always has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On output that follows that format you can just use the basic sort command:

```
sort -k 1,2 foo.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't occur to mad that it was actually that easy.

Comment: @frixhax - that's fine, it's nice when it turns out easy!